# react-native-firebase resend message code

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm looking a way to resend sms code in phone authentication in [react-native-firebase.](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase)

**phone verify number function**

```
   confirmPhone = async (phoneNumber) => {
    const phoneWithAreaCode = phoneNumber.replace(/^0+/, '+972');

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        firebase.auth().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneWithAreaCode)
            .on('state_changed', async (phoneAuthSnapshot) => {
                switch (phoneAuthSnapshot.state) {
                    case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.AUTO_VERIFIED:
                        UserStore.setVerificationId(phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId)
                        await this.confirmCode(phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId, phoneAuthSnapshot.code, phoneAuthSnapshot)
                        res(phoneAuthSnapshot)

                        break

                    case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.CODE_SENT:
                        UserStore.setVerificationId(phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId)
                        res(phoneAuthSnapshot)
                        break

                    case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.AUTO_VERIFY_TIMEOUT:
                        UserStore.setVerificationId(phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId)
                        UserStore.setErrorCodeAuthentication('SMS code has expired')
                        res(phoneAuthSnapshot)


                    case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.ERROR:
                        if (phoneAuthSnapshot.error) {
                            this.showMessageErrorByCode(phoneAuthSnapshot.error.code)

                        }

                        rej(phoneAuthSnapshot)
                        break

                }
            })
    })
}

 confirmCode = async (verificationId, code, phoneAuthSnapshot) => {
    try {
        const credential = await firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, code)
        UserStore.setCodeInput(code)
        UserStore.setUserCredentials(credential)
        AppStore.setAlreadyVerifiedAuto(true)
        await this.authenticate(credential)
        return credential
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        this.showMessageErrorByCode(e.code)
    }
}
```

what I tried to do for resend sms is to call again verifyPhoneNumber when user not get his sms code, but it's not works and I don't get sms again, if user not get in first time or if he already got sms and the sms code is expired.

```
    resendeCode =  async()=>{
    const { AppStore, UserStore } = this.props
    try {
        AppStore.setLoading();
        UserStore.setErrorCodeAuthentication('')

        let { verificationId } = await FirebaseService.confirmPhone(phoneNumber); // call confirmPhone function above again

        this.props.UserStore.setVerificationId(verificationId)

        AppStore.setLoading();
    }catch(e){
        AppStore.setLoading();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To resend just add second parameter as true in 
signInWithPhoneNumber("1234567891", true)
and call this method again with resend.
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/721#issuecomment-403295962

Comment: Hello, I use signInWithPhoneNumber in "signIn" screen and i pass the [confirmResult](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/phone-auth#1.-Trigger-phone-auth) as a param into a specific screen "confirmation" to use it in verification now, how can i call the signInWithPhoneNumber method to resend the code again ?